# Upgrade docker from 1.11 to 1.13

Tags: docker

I'm running Debian 8.5 Jessie on the host.

So I'm trying to run docker inside of docker:

```
$ docker info
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.23)
```

Current version of docker on the host:

```
root@runner:~# docker -v
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
```

So I want to bump the version, I see 1.13 is out so I'd like that. This is where the problem is, how do I upgrade it?

After seeing this page: https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/ it seems like there are different types of Docker. How do I find out which one I'm using (I inherited this project) and how to upgrade it. I've read that `docker-machine upgrade` works, however docker machine is not recognized on my system.

So how do I upgrade my docker?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm very strange. I followed this: https://docs.docker.com/cs-engine/1.13/upgrade/#ubuntu-1404-lts-or-1604-lts and it seemed to work. Extremely poor documentation from Docker.

Version jumped from `1.11` to `17.05.0-ce` now. The docker in docker is now working however.